# How to pass data to TabBar Class when PageView onPageChanged in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to know how to pass data from one class to another class.

**Main CLASS**

```
 void WhenPageScroll() {
int USERID = int.parse(complexTutorial.data[_pageController.page.toInt()].userId);
print("ID $USERID");
Tut(int.parse(complexTutorial.data[_pageController.page.toInt()].userId));


}
```

**Tut Class**

```
class Tut extends StatefulWidget {

  Tut(this.USERID);


 final int USERID;

  @override


_TutState  createState() => _TutState();

}

class _TutState extends State<Tut>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(child: LoadTut(),);


 }

  LoadTut(){
return Center(child: Text("CENTER TEXT WITH " + widget.USERID.toString()));
  }

}
```

i am using this method but no working how can i do that on page Scrolled?

Note : when i am using setState then whole page are reload but i want to reload only Tut on Scrolled.

Thanks Team.

Comment: Can you add more details to your description, I don't see any tab bar, neither the page view, would be helpful to help you do something on scroll.

Comment: Most simple way to do it is to have an index for your pages, and build widget from it, and just use setState (if you want it to be simple, you can later on use a value notifier and value notifierbuilder to rebuild just what you need)

Comment: can you please share demo codes?

Comment: PageView(
      controller: tutController,
      onPageChanged: (profilePage){ WhenUserRequestingForProfile(); } );

Comment: its my PageView

Comment: TabBarView(
                                  children: [
                                    PublishedVideosByUsers(USERID),
                                  ]
                              );

Comment: TabBar code is here